# How to combine 2 arrays of different lengths while dropping part of one array?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, filtering

I have 2 arrays

array 1: `Array ( [0] => Merc [1] => # [2] => BM [3] => & [4] => Lotus )`

array 2: `Array ( [0] => 6740 [1] => 4565 [2] => 3423 )`

The goal is to combine the 2 arrays and end up with:

`$result = ['Merc' => 6740, 'BM' => 4565, 'Lotus' => 3423];`

There is a fair amount of guidance on this already, I know, and I have read up on it but array manipulation is new to me and somehow I just cannot get my head around the logic and syntax.

Please could someone with an experienced eye tell me where I am going wrong.

I have tried:

```
... 
//// lets echo the arrays to make sure they are correct     
print_r($car);?><br><?php
print_r($part);?><br><?php

//// lets combine the 2 arrays to get an associative array      
$result = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($car); $i++){
    if (($car[$i] == "&")||($car[$i] == "#")){
        $i = ($i + 1);
    }

    foreach($car as $car) {                 
        foreach($part as $part) {
            $result[] = array(
                $car => $part,
            );
        }
    }   
}
print_r($result);
```

The output for this is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Merc] => 6740 ) [1] => Array ( [BM] => 4565 ) [2] => Array ( [Lotus] => 3423 ))
```

The special characters to be stripped will only ever be `#` or `&`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php#111668 Try this it may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out the unwanted elements and combine them.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6jbpZ))

```
$cars=['Merc','#','BM','&','Lotus'];
$parts=[6740,4565,3423];

$cars=array_diff($cars,['#','&']);
var_export(array_combine($cars,$parts));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Merc' => 6740,
  'BM' => 4565,
  'Lotus' => 3423,
)
```

---

p.s. You could also filter with [ctype_alpha()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) like this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/64Wd7))

```
$cars=array_filter($cars,'ctype_alpha');  // only retain elements that are fully comprised of letters
```

Comment: @redant My method is successful with your sample data.  Does it work for all of your real project data?  If not, you will need to improve your question with some additional sample data, so that we can see how your data can vary.

Comment: I am happy to explain, but I don't understand your question.  The OP wants to filter out the symbols (that is the job of `array_diff()`) then generate an array using `$cars` as keys and `$parts` as values (that is the job of `array_combine()`).

Comment: Agree! `array_diff` will filter. but here it is merging two arrays without checking key. What if such scenario comes when I need to check the key before merging it? I would love to understand that

Comment: That is why I have asked the OP if my method works for all cases.

Comment: PHP has a specific function that does the job of combining the arrays as key-value pairs. You are reinventing a native function call with your foreach loop (incorrectly).  There is no improved control with your method.

Comment: @mickmacusa  Tested and works a treat. Simple and elegant solution for my situation. Was unaware of array_diff. More ammo to my arsenal. Appreciated.